# i have a problem with react ,, i want to have 2 navbar styles in app

Tags: reactjs

this is my App Code

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="main-page">
    <Navbar />
    <Cursor />
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/"
        exact
        render={() => (
          <Home
            infos={infos}
            info={info}
            nextProperty={nextProperty}
            prevPropery={prevPropery}
          />
        )}
      />
      <Route path="/art" component={Art} />
      <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

i need to show navbar in home like this but when i open a new page with react router i want it no height and no color

[image: this is home page and it's ok]

[image: i want the main nav ant it's on top i want it like as bottom on picturereac]

[image: i want the bottom .. navbar on top it's from home and i want only the second on with a new style]

Comment: i want the navbar to be like in the second img bottom not top

Comment: can you share your code in sandbox?

Comment: it's very huge files ... but you understand what i mean?

Comment: you want header links in bottom also right?... and share your Navbar component also

Comment: no i added one more picture to describe ... i only want a new navbar in bottom i don't want the top one

Comment: both navbar having same links? as i can see in image

Comment: you have any account to talk with you and explain what i need please it's very important

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="main-page">
    <Navbar />
    <Cursor />
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/"
        exact
        render={() => (
          <Home
            infos={infos}
            info={info}
            nextProperty={nextProperty}
            prevPropery={prevPropery}
          />
        )}
      />
      <Route path="/art" component={Art} />
      <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
    <Navbar />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```